# Problem with data showed in a recycler view when user log out and log in firebase realtime

Tags: kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have a weird behavior with a recyclerview. The app is a kind of social network where users publish post and I look for all the post of all users that authentifated user has bookmarked. My app works fine the first time an user logins. But if the user log out, and later log in, the first post it's not showed. But If the user start over again the app it works properly. I'm really lost why it's happening.
This is a picture of part of my database, but I can read the correctly. I think the problem has to be with the recyclew view.But not sure
[image]

Here is the code where I search the data. I use two functions buscarUsuarioSeguidos which store an array with the list of user's id that later I use to look for user's posts with mostrarPublicacionesSeguidas.

```
 private fun buscarUsuariosSeguidos(usuarioUid:String){
        //BUSCAMOS EN LA TABLA SEGUIR CADA ENTRADA DONDE APAREZCA COMO SEGUIDOR EL USUARIO AUTENTIFICADO
        val seguidoresRef= referenciaBD.child("Seguir").child(usuarioUid).child("Siguiendo")
        // LIMPIAMOS LAS PUBLICACIONES SEGUIDAS
        usuariosSeguidosUid?.clear()
        //CARGAMOS LAS PUBLICACIONES EN EL RECYCLERVIEW DATACHANGE SE ENCARGA DE CARGAR LOS DATOS
        seguidoresRef.addValueEventListener(object :ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    for (snap in snapshot.children)
                        //RECUPERAMOS LA CLAVE DE CADA CHILDREN QUE REALMENTE ES EL UID DEL USUARIO
                        snap.key?.let { (usuariosSeguidosUid as ArrayList<String>).add(it) }
                }
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })
    }
    //ESTA FUNCION BUSCA LAS PUBLICACIONES DE TODOS LOS USUARIOS QUE SIGUE EL USUARIO AUTENTIFICADO
    private fun mostrarPublicacionesSeguidas() {
        //CREAMOS LA QUERY DE BUSQUEDA QUE APUNTA A LA TABLA PUBLICACIONES
        val publicacionRef = referenciaBD.child("Publicaciones")
        //listaPublicaciones?.clear()
        publicacionRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            //CARGAMOS TODOS LOS DATOS DE LA TABLA POSTS EN EL RECYCLERVIEW DATACHANGE SE ENCARGA DE CARGAR LOS DATOS
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                //LIMPIAMOS LA LISTA DE PUBLICACIONES
                listaPublicaciones?.clear()
                for (snapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    // SE VA RECUPÈRANDO CADA PUBLICACION
                    val publicacion = snapshot.getValue(Publicacion::class.java)
                    // Y SE RECORRE EL ARRAY CON LOS UID DE LOS USUARIOS SEGUIDOS PARA VER SI SE DEBE MOSTRAR
                    for (usuarioUid in usuariosSeguidosUid as ArrayList<String>)
                        // EN CASO DE QUE SE ENCUENTRE CONICIDENCIA SE AÑADE LA PUBLICACION A SU LISTA
                        if (usuarioUid == publicacion!!.nombreUsuario ){
                            listaPublicaciones?.add(publicacion!!)
                        }
                }
                //invertimos la lista para que los ultimos posts esten os primero
                listaPublicaciones!!.reverse()
                //SE ACTUALIZA EL LISTADO DE PUBLICACIONES MOSTRADOR EN EL ADAPTADOR
                publicacionAdaptador?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                //VER QUE HACE
            }
        })
    }
```

And this is the function to log out.

```
   private fun desconectarUsuario(){
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
        val intent = Intent(context,IdentificarseActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Thank

Comment: Step 1 is to stop ignoring errors and implement `onCancelled`. At its minimum that should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`. After that, it's hard to say what's going on in the complex flow you describe, so it's more likely we can help if you debug locally. So: If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** variable or line that doesn't have the value or doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: That's the problem I've debugged but I can't find the mistake In fact without touching anything a couple of minutes later the recyclew view updates alone and show the correct data in the first place....it's really weird

Comment: After debugging again I've double checked that when I used debugg there is no error. I'm starting to think that the way I use to look for the information is so badly optimised that it requires a second to finish the query....and thats why the last element, I reverse the list for the recycler view, it¡s not shown...please @Frank van Puffelen can you check I the way I use to look for the infomation is appropiated?....I'm almost sure It's a problem of efficiency

Comment: Efficient -> asynchronous behavior? If so, that could well be - but I'm having a hard time seeing any problems with asynchronous behavior, possibly in part because so much of the code and comments are in a language that I'm not familiar enough with.

Comment: Wel...After days trying to fix it I've done...but really  I don't know why it works now.... I've calling mostrarPublicacionesSeguidas()  just after the "if" in buscarUsuariosSeguidos() and  all it going well....do you have any explanation to that @FrankvanPuffelen? ...It's too weird for me. Thanks in advace

Comment: Good to hear you got it working @Monrac!  --- I don't know what was going wrong. Going forward I recommend ensuring all code (and comments in there) you post are in English to maximize the number of folks who can help.